# mPDF & char is not encoded, how i can do?

Tags: php, html, mpdf

mPDF not convert the character ' & ' and makes all that follows is not translatable . the pdf is generated but all the code following the character ' & ' is not printed . this is my code:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <p>test example & test example</p>
    </tr>
</table>
```

i use this php code to create the pdf output:

```
<?php
$divcontent = $_POST['divcontent'];
$html='<html><head></head><body style="background-color:#FFFFFF;height:100%; width:100%;">';
$html.= $divcontent;
$html.='</body></html>';
//==============================================================

include(dirname(__FILE__)."/../../libs/MPDF57/mpdf.php");
@$mpdf=new mPDF('c');
@$mpdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');
@$stylesheet = file_get_contents(realpath(dirname(__FILE__)."/../..")."/css/style.css");
$mpdf->setFooter('{PAGENO}');
@$mpdf->WriteHTML($stylesheet,1);
@$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);

$rand = rand();
@$mpdf->Output(realpath(dirname(__FILE__)."/../..")."/file.pdf",'F');
?>
```

Comment: `<p>test example <?= htmlentities("&"); ?> test example</p>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After days I found the problem. The ajax call not coded character and now adding "encodeURIComponent (divcontent)" and passing the result to the php function, should not use "html_entity_decode", mPDF print special characters such as "&".

Answer (score 0):

use [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php)

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <p>test example <?php echo htmlspecialchars('&') ?> test example</p>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: something like: test example &amp; test example ? I have tried but it doesn't works

Comment: You might need an `echo`: `<?php echo htmlspecialchars('&') ?>`

Comment: Hell yeah. missed it. Thanks buddy

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$mpdf->charset_in='utf-8';
```

You should probably add this to the head section of the HTML :

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

Make sure that your server Apache or Nginx, use also utf-8 as default charset.

Comment: I try but it not works. After the character  ' & ' not printed text.

Answer (score 0):

mPDF 8.0.4 was embedding specific characters in my application's PDFs as blank rectangles, while all other characters rendered properly.

My issue was with the parenthesis and euro symbols in the Segoe UI TTF font.

Adding `$mpdf->useSubstitutions = true;` fixed the problem.